# How did I get a negative rep on an edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation

### Context

Yesterday I've edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122883/why-cant-i-seem-to-grasp-interfaces/124545) SO question just to improve the title as [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) say.

Surprisingly, today my reputation on this edit was removed but the edit still there.

[image: Screenshot of reputation feed]

---

### Question

How did that happen? I don't mind 2 rep of course but I'm curious.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/122883/revisions) the revisions link.

<sup>I couldn't find any duplicate, please tell me if so.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also edited [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/124545/1038015) on the same question. It's that edit [that was reverted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/124545/revisions). When the OP of the answer did that, you lost the rep you gained the previous day.

If you start from your [rep page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8303093/didix13?tab=reputation) and click on the link it does take you to that answer rather than the question.